# Error C2664 using maps

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to use a map for my pathfinding, but I'm unfortunately not very familiar with them. I'm making the assumption that the following error occurs on this line in my `Pathfinding.h` : `std::map<PathNode*, bool> mOpenMap;`

`"Error 1   error C2664: 'std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty>::pair(const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'PathNode *' to 'const std::pair<const _Kty,_Ty> &'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\xmemory0 600 1   Pac3D"`

I figured it would work as I have seen others using it in a similar manner, but either I'm doing something wrong or that's not supposed to work that way, I'm thinking the latter of the two.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to fix this? I will gladly post more code upon request.

Edit: I use `mOpenMap.emplace(start, true);` to put my first node inside, from there on out it's usually currentNode, and both are `PathNode*`

Comment: I guess you are using `mOpenMap.insert(new PathNode);`, or something similar ?

Comment: I use `mOpenMap.emplace(start, true);` before I do anything to the map

Comment: and currentNode is of `PathNode*` type, right?

Comment: @AndrewB That's a pretty important piece of information, why isn't it and the relevant code included in your post?

Comment: Yeah, I just edited my comment to be start, I forgot I do that first. Everything I'm putting in is a `PathNode*`

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I wasn't aware that was important, I'll add it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error say exactly what you need to insert.

According to the error you are inserting as @PiotrS say a pointer to `PathNode`, you need to insert the pair of `(key, value)` like `mOpenMap.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));` where **key** is of type `const PathNode*` and **value** is of type `bool`.

Sample Code:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a = 1, b = 2, c = 3;
    std::map<int*, bool> mOpenMap;
    mOpenMap.insert(std::make_pair(&a, true));
    mOpenMap.insert(std::make_pair(&b, true));
    mOpenMap.insert(std::make_pair(&c, false));
    for (auto it = mOpenMap.cbegin(); it != mOpenMap.cend(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it->first << ": " << it->second << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, thank you very much. As I said I'm not very familiar with maps so this was a very easy mistake for me. I'll be sure to avoid it next time.